# How to open PDF file directly from URL in app chooser

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I need to open a PDF file which I get from URL from JSON.

This URL does not contain file extension at the end of URL. I tried something like this:

```
        final String pdfUrl = dataUrl.replace("data", "file") + "/x?filefield=" + tf.getFieldName() + "&context=\"" + dataItemIdModOne + "\"&skipcache=1";
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Constants.userDetails, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String username = sharedPrefs.getString(Constants.user, "");
        String password = sharedPrefs.getString(Constants.pass, "");
        String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
        final String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userPassword.getBytes()));
        final Map<String, String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<>();
        extraHeaders.put("Authorization", basicAuth);
        pdfIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(pdfUrl);
                Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                target.setDataAndType(uri,"*/*");
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Authorization", basicAuth);
                target.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, bundle);

                Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please install PDF app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

I just need to present to a user an app chooser so he/she will choose with witch app to open a file, or at best, just to directly open available PDF reader on his/her device.

With this implementation, I get the app chooser, and when I try to open a file it loads, but at the end it says that it can not be opened.

So the drill with this URL is that when a URL is called it redirects to another URL which contain the PDF file itself. But I cannot see that second URL. Also when I paste the URL in browser it asks for username and password (that's why I need Basic auth).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few, if any, PDF viewers will support `http`/`https` for their `ACTION_VIEW` activities. Virtually none of them will support random `Intent` extras, such as `EXTRA_HEADERS`.

Download the PDF yourself, using your favorite HTTP client API (e.g., `HttpUrlConnection`, OkHttp). Then, use `ACTION_VIEW` to view your downloaded PDF.